# A problem on general topology

Tags: general-topology

If $T_1,T_2$ and $T_3$ be topologies on a set $X$ such that $T_1 \subset T_2 \subset T_3$ and  $(X,T_2)$ is a compact Hausdorff space.then

1. $T_1=T_2$, if $(X,T_1)$ is a Hausdorff space
2. $T_1=T_2$, if $(X,T_1)$ is a compact space
3. $T_2=T_3$, if$(X,T_3)$ is a Hausdorff space
4. $T_2=T_3$, if $(X,T_3)$ is a compact space

I know that  a topological space is said to be compact if every open cover has a finite subcover and Hausdorff means distinct elements have disjoint open neighborhoods.

I can't understand how shall I solve it? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you supposed to **prove** are four of those statements, or are you supposed to **prove or disprove** each statement after deciding which ones are true?